# Read access violation using lock xcmpchg16b _InterlockedCompareExchange128

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook

I'm trying to hook a function with a lock xcmpchg16b. I have tried about 20 different things.

Expected result:

```
In real func
In hook func
```

Result in **Debug** build:

```
Exception thrown at 0x..: 0xC0000005 Access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I'm not sure why it is trying to read from 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, none of the pointers go there.

In a **Release** build, it doesn't crash! But it doesn't hook the function either.

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int RealFunc()
{
    printf("In real func\n");
    return 2;
}

int HookFunc()
{
    printf("In hook func\n");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD dwOld;
    if (!VirtualProtect(&RealFunc, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOld))
    {
        printf("Unable to make mem RWX.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    RealFunc();

    __declspec(align(16)) PVOID ProcAddress = &RealFunc;
    __declspec(align(16)) LONG64 Restore[2];

    Restore[0] = 0x0000000025ff9090;    // nop, nop, jmp [rip + 0]
    Restore[1] = (LONG64)&HookFunc;

    _InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)ProcAddress, Restore[0], Restore[1], Restore);

    RealFunc();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the function documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh972640(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Two things you should try: (1) Make sure ICE128 behaves as you expect on ordinary data memory. (2) Try setting the page protections to `PAGE_READWRITE` before modifying the code, and then `PAGE_EXECUTE` before calling into it.  Windows might be _silently_ refusing to make a page simultaneously writable and executable (that is, I wonder if maybe VirtualProtect(..., PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, ...) doesn't report failure, but doesn't do anything either).

Comment: RW+X pages have other problems, like incoherency between data and instruction caches.  Your code modification likely never makes it out of the L1 data cache.

Comment: @zwol I couldn't do `PAGE_READWRITE` because then `main()` will not be executable. However, I can overwrite the memory in a non-atomic way, so page is getting RWX permissions. I am unable to use `ICE128` to change ordinary data either.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point but doesn't seem to be root cause. I have added `FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), &RealFunc, 0x1000);` but still fails.

Comment: your code wrong . what is `ComparandResult` ? wrong.  Restore[1], Restore[0] must be - in this order

Comment: InterlockedCompareExchange only perform an exchange if the *(last argument) is equal to *(first argument). It will also crash miserably if all the parameters are not 16-bytes aligned, which is not necessary true in your case and might explain why it does not crash in release builds

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > General > "Enable incremental linking" = No.,

Comment: in general functions must not be 16 byte aligned. so `InterlockedCompareExchange128` not useful at all for hook

Answer (score 0):

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)ProcAddress, 
    Restore[0], Restore[1], Restore);
```

this is of course  wrong. if look for function signature

```
unsigned char __cdecl InterlockedCompareExchange128(
  _Inout_ LONGLONG volatile *Destination,
  _In_    LONGLONG          ExchangeHigh,
  _In_    LONGLONG          ExchangeLow,
  _Inout_ LONGLONG          *ComparandResult
);
```

second operand is *ExchangeHigh* and third is *ExchangeLow* - so must be `Restore[1], Restore[0]` but not `Restore[0], Restore[1]`. also `ComparandResult` must hold original function data. so it can not be `Restore`.

also note next, from MSDN:

> The parameters for this function must be aligned on a 16-byte
>   boundary; otherwise, the function will behave unpredictably on x64
>   systems.

but which parameters ? all ? obvious that no. for example `ExchangeHigh` and `ExchangeLow` is passed by value. we can use direct values here which at all have no any address. so speak about align is senseless for second and third params. really `InterlockedCompareExchange128` is converted to `lock cmpxchg16b` instruction. from intel manual

> Note that `CMPXCHG16B` requires that the destination (memory) operand be
>   16-byte aligned.

so only `Destination` must be 16-byte aligned. `ComparandResult` - not (it will be moved to `RCX:RBX` register pairs)

so `__declspec(align(16)) LONG64 Restore[2];` you not need at all - you can pass direct values to `InterlockedCompareExchange128`. then

`__declspec(align(16)) PVOID ProcAddress = &RealFunc;`

with `_InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)ProcAddress..`

wrong and senseless. what is different which align of `ProcAddress` ?? the memory to which **point** `ProcAddress` must be 16 byte aligned. but not  `ProcAddress` itself. and again we not need any temporary variable here. we can direct use

```
_InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)RealFunc, ...)
```

of course `RealFunc` must be be 16-byte aligned. otherwise we got exactly  `0xC0000005 Access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` exception.

so i guess that in debug mode `RealFunc` not 16 byte aligned.

> In a Release build, it doesn't crash! But it doesn't hook the function
>   either.

not hook because you use `Restore` in place `ComparandResult` and no exception because `RealFunc` was randomly 16byte align.

because in general function can have any address and must not be aligned on 16 bytes - `_InterlockedCompareExchange128` not useful at all here. also this is only for *x64*, not for *x86*

code (which anyway not hook function, if `RealFunc` not aligned on 16 bytes)can look like

```
int RealFunc()
{
    printf("In real func\n");
    return 2;
}

int HookFunc()
{
    printf("In hook func\n");
    return 1;
}

int xxx()
{
    DWORD dwOld;

    if (VirtualProtect(RealFunc, 2*sizeof(PVOID), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOld))
    {
        RealFunc();

#if defined(_M_X64)

        if (!((LONG_PTR)RealFunc & 15))
        {
            LONG64 Comparand[2] = { ((LONG64*)RealFunc)[0], ((LONG64*)RealFunc)[1] };

            InterlockedCompareExchange128((LONG64*)RealFunc, (LONG64)HookFunc, 0x0000000025ff9090, Comparand);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bad function address %p\n", RealFunc);
        }

#elif defined(_M_IX86)

        static PVOID pvHookFunc = HookFunc;
        LARGE_INTEGER Exchange = { 0x25ff9090, (LONG)&pvHookFunc };
        LONG64 Comparand;

        memcpy(&Comparand, RealFunc, sizeof(Comparand));
        InterlockedCompareExchange64((LONG64*)RealFunc, Exchange.QuadPart, Comparand);

#else 
#error not implemented
#endif

        FlushInstructionCache(NtCurrentProcess(), RealFunc, 2*sizeof(PVOID));

        if (dwOld != PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
        {
            VirtualProtect(RealFunc, 2*sizeof(PVOID), dwOld, &dwOld);
        }

        RealFunc();
    }

    return 0;
}
```